# Why Polmyer iron-ajax will not auto request when params change?

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

HTML

```
<iron-ajax auto id="ajaxWeapons"
                 verbose="true"
                 url="[[api.items.url]]"
                 params="[[api.items.params]]"
                 debounce-duration="100"
                 handle-as="json"
                 last-response="{{items}}"></iron-ajax>
```

Script

```
app.view = 'category';
app.api.items.params.page = page;
app.api.items.params.category = this.categories.find((v)=>v.code === category).id;
```

The iron-ajax will only request once, but when I change the `params.category` it will not request again, what should I do ?

**EDIT**

If I do `app.set('api.weapons.params',{size:18,category:1})`, the iron-ajax will request again, `app.set('api.weapons.params.category',1)` will not.

**UPDATE**

I try to use computed binding to work this out

HTML

```
      <iron-ajax auto id="ajaxWeapons"
                 verbose="true"
                 url="[[api.weapons.url]]"
                 params="{{getParams(api.weapons.params,api.weapons.params.size,api.weapons.params.category)}}"
                 debounce-duration="100"
                 handle-as="json"
                 last-response="{{weapons}}"></iron-ajax>
```

SCRIPT

```
app.getParams = function (params) {
    console.log('Do params ', params);
    return this.extend({}, params);
};
```

But that's no works expected,the `getParams` never get called, even `api.weapons.params,api.weapons.params.size,api.weapons.params.category` are both `!= undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params object is not being notified of the child changes and as you're aware, `set` or `notifyPath` doesn't resolve the issue.

Currently the only way I can get this scenario to work is by calling `generateRequest` directly after a param change.

```
this.$.ajaxWeapons.generateRequest();
```

To dynamically call this when needed you can add an observer:

```
observers: {
  '_testParamsChanged(testParams.*)'
},

_testParamsChanged: function(changeRecord) {
  this.$.ajaxWeapons.generateRequest();
}
```

Comment: Currently I use `generateRequest`, but there is too much to observe and call the `generateRequest `, I was wonder `{{api.weapons.params::target-change-event}}` will work for this if I notify params when sub properties change.

Comment: My app is create by `var app = document.querySelector('#app');`, how to add extra observers

Comment: Your app should be defined as a Polymer element like `<my-app></my-app>` and be inserted into the `body` of your `index.html` page.

Comment: Still leaning polymer, I give up trying and use [observe-js](https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js),I think the internal is the same as you way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use two way data-binding. [Polymer's documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html) says that:

> Square brackets ([[]]) create one-way bindings. Data flow is downward, host-to-child, and **the binding never modifies the host property**.
>
> Curly brackets ({{}}) create automatic bindings. Data flow is one-way
> or two-way, depending whether the target property is configured for
> two-way binding.

So, I suppose that your code should be something like this:

```
<iron-ajax auto id="ajaxWeapons"
             verbose="true"
             url="{{api.items.url}}"
             params="{{api.items.params}}"
             debounce-duration="100"
             handle-as="json"
             last-response="{{items}}"></iron-ajax>
```

Even, you may need to use an observer to notifying changes in the properties of your object. [Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#observing-path-changes) you can find an example of *Observing path changes*.

#### Edit

From `<iron-ajax>` [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax):

> With auto set to true, the element performs a request whenever its url, params or body properties are changed. Automatically generated requests will be debounced in the case that multiple attributes are changed sequentially.
>
> **Note: The params attribute must be double quoted JSON.**
>
> You can trigger a request explicitly by calling generateRequest on the
> element.

That is the reason why 'app.set (' api.weapons.params.category ', 1) `is not working.

Comment: Isn't this host to child only?